# How to develop the site to switch between multiple languages?

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, multilingual

I have developed the website in html5. In this I have an language selection option, now it is in English. If I select any other language, then it should show the contents in that language. I don't want to use the Google translator to translate the content. I have the content in all languages. If any tags or methods in html5 or HTML to get and display the contents specific to that language?

Comment: u need to load the corresponding language html file when suppose a dropdown list of languages one is selected.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://eligrey.com/blog/post/passive-localization-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. whether, 1) I need to have the different html files for each of the languages? 2) I need to have only the contents(English/German) in different text files without the html tags? which is possible working logic?

Comment: We have placeholders that can be changed on the server using i18n or on client using javascript. Depending on the amount of text you can do either

Answer (score 3):

You can use Javascript localization (this is one of your tags, so I guess you'd use it).

What you can do is a quick-check for the locale of the user, thus filling the page with a matching localization of your contents.

Here's a quick and dirty example. (note: this is purely dynamic)

```
locale = (navigator["language"] || "en").split("-")[0];

localization = {
    "de": "Hallo Benutzer!",
    "en": "Hey user!"
};

text = localization[locale] || localization["en"];

e = document.createElement("span");
e.innerHTML = text;
document.body.appendChild(e);
```

Comment: Note: the ".split("-")[0]" makes sure we get a plain string. The locale of a user is typically specified by language-country. That is, there's for instance "en-US" or "de-DE"; we're good to go if we only have to specify non-country-dependent localizations.

Comment: Except I HATE it when my mail interface changes to whatever language they speak in the country I happen to be in. Please make sure there is a flag to click and a cookie to remember my choice

Comment: This is not a question of what you like — if you want more, implement more.

Answer (score 2):

If your website is a static one, then you can clone your site for each language, by using language specific content, and access each version with a different base url ( domain/en/..., domain/es/....).

Comment: Yes my page is static. But I have more than 50 files in my site. If I need to clone to each language then it took more work and more files. Is there any tool or plugin or JavaScript function to retrieve the content from xml or text file for based on the language selection?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get your pages translated into whatever languages you want.

Duplicate your entire web structure per language so you end up with

www.example.com/en/..
www.example.com/fr/..

etc

Generally people give use a flag to indicate the language and redirect to the corresponding language page.

Answer (score 1):

No.

HTML allows you to specify the language you are working in with `lang` attributes, but it provides no specific features for (manually or automatically) translation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then how to make visitors to switch between languages for their selection? whether I need to create sites for each and every language?

Comment: Usually there would be a mix of language-specific and shared code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multilingual makes for a useful starting point.